# Finding lebesgue integral of the piecewise function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by  $\mu(x)=\begin{cases} 
      x^2-1 & x\ \leq 0 \\
      x^2 & x > 0\\
     \end{cases}$

and let $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      2 & x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [-2,1] \\
      4 & x\in [-2,1] \setminus\mathbb{Q} \\
      0 & x\notin [-2,1] \\
     \end{cases}$

> Use the definition of Lebesgue integral for simple functions to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mu(dx)$

Is this the proper way to calculate this?

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mu(dx)$ = $\int_{[-2,1]} fd\mu = \int_{[-2,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} fd\mu + \int_{[-2,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}} fd\mu + \int_{[-\infty,2)\cup(1,\infty]} fd\mu$

where $$\int_{[-2,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} fd\mu = \int2\mu([-2,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}) = \int2(x^3)dx$$ 
$$\int_{[-2,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}} fd\mu = \int3\mu([-2,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}) = \int3(x^3)dx$$
$$\int_{[-\infty,2)\cup(1,\infty]} = \int 0\mu([-\infty,2)\cup(1,\infty]) = \int0(x^2-1)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to realize that $\mathbb Q$ is a null-set. This means that $\mu([-2,1]\cap \mathbb Q) \le \mu(\mathbb Q) = 0$. Also it means that $\mu([-2,1]\setminus \mathbb Q) = \mu([-2,1])$.

Also I think that $\mu(x)=...$ means that $\mu(E) = \int_E \mu(x)dx$. Your integral for the second part looks odd. I'd get it to:

$$\int_[-2,1]\setminus Q f d\mu = \int_{-2}^1 f d\mu = \int_{-2}^04(x^2-1)dx + \int_0^1 4x^2dx$$

for the third the result is correct, but you can directly use that the integral of a zero-function is always zero.